# Error in counting total characters in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textarea. I restrict users to enter only 100 characters in that textarea using jQuery. It works fine..But my code counts space also. I don't want my function to count space as a character. All other inputs from keyboard be counted as a character excluding space.

Here's my jQuery function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var totalChars      = 100; //Total characters allowed in textarea
    var countTextBox    = $('#counttextarea') // Textarea input box
    var charsCountEl    = $('#countchars'); // Remaining chars count will be displayed here

    charsCountEl.text(totalChars); //initial value of countchars element
    countTextBox.keyup(function() { //user releases a key on the keyboard
        var thisChars = this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, '').length; //get chars count in textarea
        if(thisChars > totalChars) //if we have more chars than it should be
        {
            var CharsToDel = (thisChars-totalChars); // total extra chars to delete
            this.value = this.value.substring(0,this.value.length-CharsToDel); //remove excess chars from textarea
        }else{
            charsCountEl.text( totalChars - thisChars ); //count remaining chars
        }
    });
});
```

my HTML Code is given below:

```
<textarea name="counttextarea" id="counttextarea" cols="30" rows="8"></textarea><br />
<span name="countchars" id="countchars"></span> Characters Left
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6C8zn/

Comment: `this.value.replace(/ /g, '').length;` or `this.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length;` http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/6PkeJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression is not correct.

Instead of

```
var thisChars = this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, '').length; //get chars count in textarea
```

Use either of these

```
var thisChars = this.value.replace(/ /g, '').length;  
var thisChars = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/6PkeJ/)